# Avoid overlapping geom_point and geom_text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, geom-text

How can I avoid that these 2 layers in ggplot2 overlap? I try to display the text so that they are not laying above the points.

`check_overlap` does a great job with avoiding that the text overlaps itself, but not with other layers.

I also tried the library `geom_text_repel`, but this library does not support `check_overlap` and shows the text for every data point.

But I need to not have the text for every point, like `check_overlap` does.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = CPI, y = HDI)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Region), shape=21, size=4, position = "identity") +
  geom_text(data = dat, aes(label = Country), size=4, check_overlap = TRUE)
```

Comment: [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/index.html)

Comment: Can you remove the repeated labels at each data point, & then use `geom_text_repel` from ggrepel?

Comment: i have tried `geom_text_repel` but it shows a label or text for every datapoint in the `geom_point`, what i dont want.

Answer (score 2):

`geom_text_repel` will not create text labels for the empty string `""`. However, the text labels will repel away from the unlabeled data points.

Try this:

```
# Hide text labels for the first 3 data points
idx <- c(1,2,3)

dat$CountryLabel      <- dat$Country
dat$CountryLabel[idx] <- ""

library(ggrepel)
ggplot(...) + geom_text_repel(data = dat, aes(label = CountryLabel))
```

Comment: This is not a general solution to the problem. We want to avoid the overlap between geom_text and geom_point.